# Recover from incorrect rebase or merge

Tags: git

We have 2 branches: **master** and **free**. Most of the code is written in **master** and merged into **free** (not the other way). Now, at some point something went wrong: code that should only be in branch **free** now appears in **master**. It seems like somebody merged **free** into **master** (or re-based free on top of master) and pushes this. This is silly, but we can't identify when this happened and which commit (commits) introduces this bug.

I would appreciate any advice on how to recover from this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I recovered the master branch by the following simple steps.

1. Identify the commit that pointed to a stable branch (before someone did a rebase). I used git checkout master@{YYYY-MM-DD} to identify the head of the master branch before the day it all happened. This turned out the last commit before the merge-commit with free branch (not surprisingly).
2. Branch off of the stable commit and cherry pick all the master commits (excluding the the merge commit).

Probably the most important part is the realization that rebase is not so destructive after all. It destroys the history, but not the tree. So, there is always a commit that you can revert to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-S<search-string>` option to `git log` to find which commits added or removed a particular string from a file.¹  So, if you know that the `ToasterFactory` class was only introduced on the `free` branch, you could do the following to see which merge commits brought that into `master`:

```
git log -SToasterFactory --merges master
```

... or if it might have been introduced by a rebase or cherry-pick, you can just do:

```
git log -SToasterFactory master
```

If it was a merge commit that brought in all the changes from `master`, you could try reverting that merge commit, e.g. with:

```
git revert <SHA1-OF-MERGE-COMMIT>
```

The one note of caution about that is that if you later want to remerge, you may need to [revert the revert first](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

---

¹ Strictly speaking, this option only returns commits where the number of occurences of that string in a particular file.  With git version 1.7.4 or later you can use the `-G` option instead.

Comment: Well, thank you, but this didn't really help in my case. Probably because the code in very much the same between the branches.

Comment: Presumably, though, you can identify in one file some line that shouldn't be there - in that case just run `git blame <file-with-distinctive-change>` and look for the commit that introduced that line in the left column...